# Resolving MySQL gap lock

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock, composite-key, unique-key

Need help with resolving deadlock and understanding the reason which causes it

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `billing_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `foreign_transaction_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `product_type` enum('invoice') DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `subscription_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `type` enum('payment') DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `fee` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `vat` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `status` enum('active','deleted') NOT NULL,
  `test` enum('no','yes') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `billing_id` (`billing_id`,`foreign_transaction_id`),
  KEY `subscription_id_type` (`subscription_id`,`type`),
  KEY `credit_id_type` (`credit_id`,`type`),
  KEY `product_type` (`product_type`,`product_id`),
  KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3679531 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Text from the "innodb status" report immediately after the deadlock occurs:

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2018-12-17 12:10:38 0x2f8
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 153838477815, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 446845346, OS thread handle 974, query id 88919281792 123.123.123.123 root update
INSERT  INTO mydb.`payments`
            SET `billing_id` = '11', `foreign_transaction_id` = '1416436', `product_type` = 'invoice', `product_id` = '232886', `type` = 'payment', `amount` = '9.99', `fee` = '0.454545', `vat` = '0', `status` = 'active', `test` = 'no'
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `billing_id` =  '11', `foreign_transaction_id` =  '1416436', `product_type` =  'invoice', `product_id` =  '232886', `type` =  'payment', `amount` =  '9.99', `fee` =  '0.454545', `vat` =  '0', `status` =  'active', `test` =  'no', `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1898595 page no 25610 n bits 488 index billing_id of table `mydb`.`payments` trx id 153838477815 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 61 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 0000000b; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 313431363434; asc 141644;;
 2: len 4; hex 00239264; asc  # d;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 153838477576, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 1
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 446846795, OS thread handle 760, query id 88919279740 123.123.123.123 root update
INSERT  INTO mydb.`payments`
            SET `billing_id` = '11', `foreign_transaction_id` = '1416430', `product_type` = 'invoice', `product_id` = '1317214', `type` = 'payment', `amount` = '9.99', `fee` = '0.454545', `vat` = '0', `status` = 'active', `test` = 'no'
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `billing_id` =  '11', `foreign_transaction_id` =  '1416430', `product_type` =  'invoice', `product_id` =  '1317214', `type` =  'payment', `amount` =  '9.99', `fee` =  '0.454545', `vat` =  '0', `status` =  'active', `test` =  'no', `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 1898595 page no 25610 n bits 488 index billing_id of table `mydb`.`payments` trx id 153838477576 lock_mode X locks gap before rec
Record lock, heap no 61 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 0000000b; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 313431363434; asc 141644;;
 2: len 4; hex 00239264; asc  # d;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1898595 page no 25610 n bits 488 index billing_id of table `mydb`.`payments` trx id 153838477576 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 61 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 0000000b; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 313431363434; asc 141644;;
 2: len 4; hex 00239264; asc  # d;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

I guess the reason is in composite unique index "billing_id". I'd like to know how MySQL creates the lock gap step by step in this case. And what should be done for resolving it

Answer (score 1):

- Not all deadlocks can be prevented.
- In some cases InnoDB will be pessimistic in what it locks -- this is probably far more efficient than trying a lot harder to avoid some complex conflict.
- Plan for deadlocks by testing for errors after every SQL, and being ready to `ROLLBACK` and restart the transaction.

It may help to see all the SQL in the transaction.  It *may* be that you are missing a `FOR UPDATE` that would turn a deadlock into a "lock_wait_timeout", which silently 'just works'.

**added**

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE  `billing_id` = '11',
        `foreign_transaction_id` = '1416436',
        `product_type` = 'invoice',
        `product_id` = '232886',
        `type` = 'payment',
        `amount` = '9.99',
        `fee` = '0.454545',
        `vat` = '0',
        `status` = 'active',
        `test` = 'no',
        `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`)
```

-->

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE  `product_type` = VALUES(product_type),
        `product_id` = VALUES(product_id),
        `type` = VALUES(type),
        `amount` = VALUES(amount),
        `fee` = VALUES(fee),
        `vat` = VALUES(vat),
        `status` = VALUES(status),
        `test` = VALUES(test)
```

That is, don't repeat the unique/primary keys; use `VALUES` rather than repeating the values.  (I don't know if this will help, but it seems 'right'.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There's no other sql-s within request which work with this table except one more UPDATE that run's few operations later after INSERT ODKU (from log above). Stacktrace of application shows that deadlock occurs only after first one INSERT ODKU. 
What do you think would it help to get rid of lock if I separate INSERT ODKU into 3 different queries in application code like:
`if (select from table) {
 update
} else {
 insert`

Comment: It worked well before, but last days rps grown and I started to get locks in this place. After reading a lot of articles still don't know what should be done for resolving it. I have only ideas about some changes in code, or trying to use isolation level 'read commited' insted of default

Comment: @Network_SPY - Still, it may be helpful to see more of the transaction.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. This query is not a part of db transaction, it's single. Deadlock still occurs even if it's wrapped into transaction together with other queries from that business logic